# For which of the Weierstrass elliptic function periods do this equation of the modular discriminant and the Dedekind eta function apply?

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, modular-forms, elliptic-functions, dedekind-eta-function

It is often claimed that the following equation holds for the [modular discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_elliptic_function#Modular_discriminant) $\Delta=g_2^3-27g_3^2$ of the Weierstrass elliptic funtion and the [Dedekind eta ($\eta$) function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function) for period ratio $\tau=\omega_2/\omega_1$:

> $\Delta(\tau)=(2\pi)^{12}\eta^{24}(\tau)$

But this can't apply to all values of the invariants $g_2$ and $g_3$ because for the scaled elliptic function with periods $\lambda\omega_1$ and $\lambda\omega_2$ the period ratio and thus $\eta(\tau)$ are the same but the invariants $g_2(\lambda\omega_1,\lambda\omega_2)=\lambda^{-4}g_2(\omega_1,\omega_2)$ and $g_3(\lambda\omega_1,\lambda\omega_2)=\lambda^{-6}g_2(\omega_1,\omega_2)$ and the modular discriminant $\Delta(\lambda\omega_1,\lambda\omega_2)=\lambda^{-12}g_2^3-27\lambda^{-12}g_3^2$ are different. For a given period ratio, for which values of $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ do the equation apply? Is it when the periods are the half-periods of the [Jacobi elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_elliptic_functions) (also known as twice the [Legendre complete elliptic integrals of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind))? Or is it when $\omega_1=1$? [Wolfram Functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/DedekindEta/27/01/01/) says that it's the latter, but I'm not sure if it's an authoritative enough source. Neither the Wikipedia articles linked above nor [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/23.19) make it clear.

Comment: It is as you guessed. The left side is missing a factor of $\omega_1^{12}$. What would you consider an "authoritative" source?

Comment: Maybe a book? It doesn't have to explicitly say that this equation assumes a normalization convention; if it defines the Weierstrass elliptic functions so that $\omega_1=1$, that's enough. A proof would make it clear what normalization convention is used.

Comment: Did you read the sentence in DLMF just after $23.19.3$? "where $g_2⁡,g_3$⁡ are the invariants of the lattice $\mathbf{L}$ with generators $1$ and $\tau$; see §$23.3$(i)."

Comment: @Somos Yeah, I missed that.